# React Native hybrid App Notch's backgroundColor change when url changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

Nice to meet you.
I'm going to make a hybrid app by react native

The color of the iPhone's notch area and Android's StatusBar is designed to change colors depending on a specific page (for example, if the webview page is a login page, the color of the notch (StatusBar) is blue / For other pages) purple), finding the url with onNavigationStateChange of webview was successful, but I want to ask for help on what to do in the subsequent process

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be something like this, you basically set pageName to some string based on the url you just navigated to, and if that pageName exists in your colors object then the status bar color will change to it

```
//define the colors like:
const statusbarColors = {
    login: "blue",
    default: "green"
}

//in your component set a state (pageName) based on the url you navigate to
 
<SafeAreaView 
    style={{ 
        backgroundColor: statusbarColors[pageName] ?? statusbarColors.default,
        flex: 0 
    }}
/>
<StatusBar 
    backgroundColor={statusbarColors[pageName] ?? statusbarColors.default}
/>
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    //your screen content
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise.
Can i listen to how to set a paseName in hybrid app?
-> i know useState but i don't know how to use in hybrid app

Comment: isn't it just a webview inside a react native app? just use useState to define pageName and setPageName,  and after getting the url from onNavigationStateChange just set pageName based on it

Comment: oH!! i understand perfectly!! Thank you so much.
I can make this code!

Comment: Happy to help, if my answer helped you I'd appreciate marking it as solved ^^